# Creating a blob from a local file for an angular unit test

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm trying to write a unit test for a file upload functionality we have within our angular app.  The upload method takes a File object as input.  The way I'm picturing this - perhaps because I'm coming from the Java world - I should place a sample file somewhere within the project structure, then load the file and pass it to the method which uploads it.  I can't seem to find a way to create the blob which is required to create the file.  I know that I can create a file with something like

`const testFile: File = new File(['blob'],'./file.txt');`

I don't seem to be able to figure out how to read in a file as a blob.
I have a couple of questions:

1. Am I thinking up this test correctly, or should it be done differently?
2. How can I read a local file into a blob in an angular test using typescript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, here is how I did it:

Put your file in a folder of your choice (e.g. testing-assets next to your src folder)

Edit your `karma.conf.js`  with:

```
files: [
  {
    pattern: 'testing-assets/**',
    included: false,
    watched: false,
    served: true
  }
]
```

Then in your `.spec.ts` file you can do:

```
let response = await fetch("/base/testing-assets/file.txt");
let blob: Blob = await response.blob();
```